# How to create multi level navigation?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, navigation

I created a sub level location for my menu link by drag & drop. (ex: /about/FAQ) 
I was wondering if it is possible to go another level deep (3rd level)?

example: /about/something/FAQ

Comment: This really depends on which version of SharePoint you're using

Answer (score 3):

Here are few more interesting links to get you as much information about the problem as possible:

**SP 2010:**

[Sharepoint 2010: How to add menu items at 3 or more level in quick launch -part 2](http://aanuwizard.com/2012/03/18/sharepoint-2010-how-to-add-menu-items-at-3-or-more-level-in-quick-launch-part-2/)

[3 level navigation in Sharepoint 2010](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f224e1af-613c-46ad-9863-997c10fdf926/3-level-navigation-in-sharepoint?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

[3rd Level Navigation (Sharepoint 2010)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ffdd2355-5e3f-47fd-994e-6982a3a3d02d/3rd-level-navigation)

**SP 2013:**

[SharePoint 2013 top link bar extended dropdown](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/04c1f719-f4d2-496f-98c6-db9022c795ab/sharepoint-2013-top-link-bar-extended-dropdown?forum=sharepointgeneral)

[3rd Level SharePoint SharePoint Navigation and Fly Outs](http://blog.thehensongroup.com/2013/01/13/3/)

[Two Level Cascading Drop Down in SharePoint 2013 using SPServices](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758909/Two-Level-Cascading-Drop-Down-in-SharePoint-using)

I hope these resources help you! :)

**EDIT:**

Also found this rich answer with a quick search: [How To: Global 3 Tier Hyperlink Navigation, allowing Dynamic DropDown](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112403/how-to-global-3-tier-hyperlink-navigation-allowing-dynamic-dropdown)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the coding and change the CSS.

**For sharepoint 2013**

http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Create-a-Multilevel-Hierarchical-Menu-in-SharePoint-2013-with-SuiteBar-Branding-Delegate-Control.aspx

**For SharePoint 2010:**

http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/sharepoint2010/sharepoint2010general.aspx?ID=f224e1af-613c-46ad-9863-997c10fdf926

http://erikswenson.blogspot.in/2010/07/sharepoint-2010-two-tier-global.html