# How To: Global 3 Tier Hyperlink Navigation, allowing Dynamic DropDown

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, navigation, hyperlink

I am using SharePoint 2010 Publishing Infrastructure Features, setting up Global Navigation and dynamic navigation dropdown (already changed DynamicDisplayLevels in v4master to "2"). This works very well, illustrating all subsites dynamically.

However, I would like to additionally set up custom Hyperlinks refering to other SiteCollecitons in a 3-tier-like structure.
Adding headings and Hyperlinks in the Navigation Editor, I am able to create 2 tiers (see Illustration).
Any suggestions on how to manually set up a third tier in editor?

[image: Want to create 3rd Hyperlink-Tier]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot create a heading under another heading or a link under another link in SharePoint.

What you can do is create your own sitemap file with the hierarchy you'd like and then add it into your _app_bin folder on your web front end servers.

You will also need to edit your web.config files and add a reference to your custom sitemap. Find the sitemap section on your web.config and add a line similar to the one below for MyCustomSiteMapProvider:

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="CurrentNavigation" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <add name="SPNavigationProvider" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    <add name="SPSiteMapProvider" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPSiteMapProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    ...
    <add name="MyCustomSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="/_app_bin/myCustom.sitemap" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

Then in your SharePoint master page you would find the SiteMapDataSource used by your global navigation and then change its SiteMapProvider to your custom provider like this:

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ShowStartingNode="False" SiteMapProvider="MyCustomSiteMapProvider" id="MySiteMap" runat="server"/>
```