# How to add more than 2 levels to structured navigation?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I need to implement structured navigation in order to have Audience Targeting capabilities. it appears that structured navigation only supports 2 levels. is that correct? is there a way to override without programming?

I am trying to achieve the following for left hand navigation. This navigation will be for a bi subsite of host name site collection.

Menu Item 1

- Sub Item 11

  - Sub Item 111

sharepoint enterprise 2013 sp1 farm

Answer (score 2):

With SharePoint 2010 & 2013, if you have access to your masterpage you can modify the number of dynamic navigation levels available. To do this, open the master page in SharePoint Designer and search for the ASPMenu tag. There could potentially be more than one in there, but the correct one will have an ID of "TopNavigationMenu" or something very close. The left (Quick Launch) menu will have an ID similar to "V5QuickLaunchMenu".

Once you find that, the tag will have an attribute called "MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels" which is set to 1 by default. You can change that to 2 or 3 as needed. Obviously, you don't want to go much higher, since multiple levels of menus turns into a mess fast.

There is also a setting called "StaticDisplayLevels" which affects how many levels of static links you can create.

If you don't have access to modify your master page, you'll have to use a combination of JavaScript and CSS to create your own menus dynamically and append them onto the existing navigation links.

Related Question: [How to create multi level navigation?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/112401/20982)

**UPDATE:** Apparently if you have SharePoint 2013, there is a bug with structured navigation levels that was [fixed with the August 2013 CU update](http://ericoverfield.com/sharepoint-2013-structured-navigation-dynamic-menus-fixed-august-2013-cu/).

Comment: it's not the display which is the problem - it's the creation of the menu itself. if I go to 
Site Settings : Navigation Settings  at the bottom I create the menu. It only allows the entry of 2 levels. the settings you describe don't address that issue - as I understand it.

Comment: Updated answer to include static menu links.

Answer (score 0):

you cant add more than 2 levels to structured navigation. For more than 3 levels, you need to use metadata navigation.