# Create Third level navigation in SharePoint 2013 on premise publishing site

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, global-navigation

i have created global Navigation (structural navigation) [third level navigation](https://newsignature.com/articles/no-code-global-navigation-flyout-dropdown-sharepoint-2013-online) on SharePoint online site .[image]

now i am trying to create third level navigation on SharePoint On Premise Site.
i have SharePoint on premise publishing site . but i am not able to find Edit Links button .

is that possible to create third level navigation in SharePoint on premise .
if **Possible/not possible** please  share some articles.

Comment: Here is the [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112401/how-to-create-multi-level-navigation) it's looks similar to your requirements hope it helps you.

Comment: The two questions are related, but not the same.  One is asking about the edit link, the other if a third level of nesting is possible.